# Getting TypeError while importing urllib

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, urllib2, urllib

When I write the following line of code

```
import urllib
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "socket.py", line 2, in <module>
    s = socket.socket()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

After going through various questions on SO I tried these:

```
from urllib import urlopen
```

(Same error as above)

```
>>> urllib
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

>>> urllib.urlopen()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined
```

Please help. I get a similar error when I try to import `urllib2`, `urllib3`, `requests`.

Comment: You cannot to name files with same names of python stdlib. Rename socket.py to othername

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named your file `socket.py`, hiding the standard library `socket` module. Name it something else.